# Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Name resolution failure)

Tags: grpc

I start to use Grpc framework to achieve some communication between Client/Server but i got this Exception :

**Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Name resolution failure)'**

Description : 
I am using .Net Framework 4.7 in my Environment, which it contains client (as Library), Server (as exe) and a caller(as Library) which is used to call the client.

Client Packages : Grpc (1.19.0) / Grpc.Core (1.19.0) / Grpc.Tools (1.19.0) / Goolge.Protobuf (3.7.0)
Server Packages : Grpc (1.19.0) / Grpc.Core (1.19.0) / Grpc.Tools (1.19.0) / Goolge.Protobuf (3.7.0) / Goolge.Protobuf.Tools (3.7.0)

As i understand the client is not able to connect to the server for some reason.

thanks for any help.

**Can anybody give me any Idea what is going wrong? why i am not able to connect to Server?**

The Stack :

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at GrpcStreaming.GrpcStreamingClient.Init(GrpcStreamingContext request, CallOptions options)
   at GrpcStreaming.GrpcStreamingClient.Init(GrpcStreamingContext request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NameSpaceExample.Init(String str1, String str2)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, host name was wrong.